# Google Sign Flow for Website. IDToken vs Access Token. Which one do I need?

Tags: node.js, google-signin

What I ideally want to achieve is to be able to Login with Google SignIn, and put authentication on my Nodejs server's endpoints.

What I have done till now is log in the user in the browser, and send the IdToken to the server, validate this TokenId using verifyIdToken() using this link.

https://www.google.com/search?q=verify+idToke&rlz=1C5CHFA_enIN936IN936&oq=verify+idToke&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i13l2j0i13i30l3j69i60l2.12008j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Question:
Once verified, should I generate an access_token using some package, and use that to secure my server's API? Or Use Google SignIn's IdToken as an access token for it?
Or Is there some other flow I'm not getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id_token` contains information about the user i.e. email, name, and profile picture.

If that's all that your application needs then the `access_token` won't be of use to you.

If you're trying to access/modify data belonging to the user, (i.e. trying to add an event to their calendar using the calendar api) then you need the `access_token`. The `access_token` is what will give you access to the user's account. If your application requests offline access to the user data then you will also receive something called a `refresh_token` that will let you regenerate your access token once it expires. If you add the refresh token to your `oAuthClient` it should automatically renew the access token for you when you make an api call.

Based on what you described I don't think you need the `access_token` and the `id_token` might be all you need.

More information is available on this page: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2

Comment: So once the user is verified with IDToken, and I have the details such as email id. I should use IdToken to protect server routes?

Comment: I think what I should do, is once the IdToken is validated, I should generate an access token, using some package, and use that to protect server routes. Though I'm not 100% confident on this approact.

Comment: @Jack Depends on how your app works. If you're using your own session system, you'd probably create a session for the user after they sign in and use that session cookie to protect your routes. The access token is only to access user information through Google APIs. You cannot derive an access token from an id token.

Comment: I presume your backend is in nodeJS so take a look at this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session